# Kendo UI droppable drop event not firing

Tags: events, knockout.js, foreach, kendo-ui, draggable

I have a simple application that binds to a view model using Knockout JS. It uses a foreach loop that fires the Knockout afterAdd event when a new item is added to the view model. The result is supposed to be a Kendo draggable that can be dropped on a target. For some reason I can't get the drop event on the target to fire.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chriswnichols/rk6qwsy4/)

```
<button data-bind="click: $root.add">Add</button>
```

Drop target

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    this.operations = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.add = function () {
        this.operations.push("drag");
    }.bind(this);
    this.bind = function () {
        $(".draggable").kendoDraggable({
            hint: function (e) {
                $("#console").append("<li>firing hint</li>");
                return e.clone();
            },
        });

        $(".droptarget").kendoDropTarget({
            drop: function (e) {
                $("#console").append("<li>firing drop</li>");
            }
        });

    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're instantiating the KendoDropTarget widget multiple times. If I click the Add button in your example `kendoDropTarget()` is invoked three times. If I add a guard against this (see http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/rk6qwsy4/1/) the `drop` event works as expected.

Comment: It occurred to me that might be the problem. I tried implementing some code to destroy the events before instantiating them but it didn't work. I used $("selector").unbind(".kendo-dnd"). Whenever a new member is added to operations it needs to add the draggable/droppable event after the DOM is ready.